# Query snapshot for each is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a function in Firebase. Db used Firestore. Error getting in logs

```
Error getting documents:  TypeError: querySnapshot.forEach is not a function
    at /srv/lib/index.js:147:23
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Trying to fetch **assignBy** from collection **todos**

My function:

```
// get todos collection docid when oncreate happens in todoscomments collection
exports.insert_Notifi_ontrig_todoscomments = functions.firestore
.document('todoscomments/{todoscommentsId}')
.onCreate(
    async (snapshot: { data: () => { (): any; new(): any; message: any; taskid: any; from: any; fromName: any; }; },context:any) => {

      // todos details.
      const text = snapshot.data();
      const taskid = text.taskid; // this is docid of todos collection


                  //get data of todos doc
                    const query3 = admin.firestore().collection('todos').doc(taskid)
                    await query3.get()
                    .then(function(querySnapshot: any[]) {
                      querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
                          const assignBy = doc.data().assignBy;
                          console.log(assignBy);
                      });
                  })

                          .catch(function(error: any) {
                              console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                          });


    });
```

I want to fetch value of assignBy , attaching screenshot of todos

[image]

Comment: Instead of showing a screenshot of text, please copy the text into question itself so it's easier to read.

Comment: noted, will do that in future

Comment: You can edit the question to resolve it right away and improve it for future readers and also Google searches.  Use the edit link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: i have done that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is not a Query object at all:

```
const query3 = admin.firestore().collection('todos').doc(taskid)
```

`query3` is a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) type object that refers to a single document.  When you `get()` that, it returns a promise that yields a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) with a single document (not a QuerySnapshot).  As you can see from the API documentation, it has no forEach method, as there is only ever 0 or 1 document in the result.  If you want that document, you should first check to see if it [exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#exists), the just call [data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) on it directly.